# I need to add form files as model instances dynamically in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, python-3.6

I'm trying to do something like this:

There's a form in my web page and has a "select files button" so you can upload multiple files at once. My problem is that I need "get" that files and add each of them to be a model instance, is there possible?

Comment: Please provide a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example of this in the [django docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html#apphook-menus)

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
    file_field = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(
            attrs={'multiple': True}
        )
    )
```

`views.py`

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import FileFieldForm

class FileFieldView(FormView):
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'  # Replace with your template.
    success_url = '...'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        if form.is_valid():
        for f in files:
            ...  # Do something with each file.
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

In terms of the model being dynamic, adding any number of files to fields, you can perhaps look at using [`JSONField`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield) in MySQL or using [Hstore](http://postgresguide.com/cool/hstore.html) with PostGres which is very similar. Essentially these fields store Json data & you can interpret it when you use the field.